# Boot-strapping Spring Data JPA without XML

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

What is the Java `@Configuration` equivalent to:

```
<repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />
```

in [Spring Data JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa)? I am trying to get rid of XML configuration in favour to `@Configuration` classes, however reading through [JpaRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/JpaRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser.java) sources is fruitless.

The closest what I can get is:

```
@Bean
public RepositoryFactorySupport repositoryFactory() {
    return new JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager())
}

@Bean
public BookDao bookDao() {
    return repositoryFactory().getRepository(BookDao.class)
}
```

However the `<repositories/>` tag is much more functional: it *automatically* creates DAO for all interfaces extending `CrudRepository` found on CLASSPATH. Also it seems like my solution does not apply transactions to DAOs as opposed to default Spring Data JPA behaviour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring Data JPA introduced `@EnableJpaRepositories`. See the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.java-config) for details.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like not possible yet: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-69

Comment: Thanks for the link. It has been fixed in 1.2.